# how can I make my door open from a specific distance c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to add doors to my Unity project and so far I have gotten the code to work with my door but I can open it from any distance in the scene. I want to be able to only open it from a small distance away but I cannot figure out how.

```
public class Door : MonoBehaviour
{
public bool doorIsOpen;
public Transform closedPos;
public Transform openPos;
public float openSpeed;
public float openRadius;

void Update()
{
    if(Physics.CheckSphere(gameObject.transform.position, openRadius))
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
         {
            doorIsOpen = !doorIsOpen;
         }
    }         

    if(doorIsOpen == true)
    {
        OpenDoor();
    }
    if(doorIsOpen == false)
    {
        CloseDoor();
    }

}

void OpenDoor()
{
    doorIsOpen = true;
    gameObject.transform.position = openPos.position;
    gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("OpenDoor");
    gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("DoorIsClosed", false);
    gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("DoorIsOpen", true);
}

void CloseDoor()
{
    doorIsOpen = false;
    gameObject.transform.position = closedPos.position;
    gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("CloseDoor");
    gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("DoorIsOpen", false);
    gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("DoorIsClosed", true);
}
```

}

Comment: you can and an if statement in your opendoor method to check the distance and and return if it's far

Answer (score 0):

## Prerequisites

Add a sphere with a collision body around the door instance in Unity. This sphere functions as the radius which will trigger the ChangeDoorState method.

## Change the update method

The update will look at any collisions happening in the specified sphere. If there is at least one object in range (the collision sphere) of the door, then it opens or closes the door instance. Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html

```
    void Update()
    {
        Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(center, radius);
        if (hitColliders.Length > 0)
        {
            ChangeDoorState();
        }
    }
```

## Merged the OpenDoor and CloseDoor methods

```
        void ChangeDoorState()
        {
            doorClosureState = doorClosure ? true : false;
            gameObject.transform.position = doorClosureState ? closedPos.position : openPos.postition;
            gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("DoorClosure");
            gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("DoorIsOpen", doorClosureState);
            gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("DoorIsClosed", !doorClosureState);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the value of 'openRadius', the game is creating a sphere at gameObject.transform.position with a radius of 'openRadius' and checking if there is any colliders overlapping the sphere.

```
//...
if(Physics.CheckSphere(gameObject.transform.position, openRadius))
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that you permanently set the triggers in every frame. You would only want to do so when you hit the key.

Then also [`Physics.CheckSphere`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.CheckSphere.html) checks whether there is **any** collider within the range. This could be any collider, not only the player. To make sure it only works if the player is the one in range you should definitely use [Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) and give the player its own layer e.g. "Player". Then you can pass the `layerMask` parameter to make sure the doors only check for the player's layer.

so I would simply use

```
// if possible already reference this in the Inspector
[SerializeField] private Animator _animator;

[Tooltip("Here select only the Layer(s) which you assigned to your Player object(s)")]
[SerializeField] LayerMask _playerLayer;

private void Awake()
{
    // as fallback get it ONCE on runtime
    if(!_animator) _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

private void Update()
{
    // Afaik the Key is way cheaper to check so do it first
    // and use physics only if actually necessary
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        // Only check for the Player's Layer and ignore other colliders
        if(Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, openRadius, _playerLayer.value))
        {
            ToggleDoorState();
        }
    }
}

// Since manually changing the flag in the Inspector will not have
// any effect anymore in order to be able to test it you can use 
// the context menu of this component in the Inspector
[ContextMenu(nameof(ToggleDoorState))]
private void ToggleDoorState()
{
    // invert the flag
    doorIsOpen = !doorIsOpen;

    // use the flag in ternary expressions
    transform.position = doorIsOpen ? openPos.position : closedPos.position;
    _animator.SetTrigger(doorIsOpen ? "OpenDoor" : "CloseDoor");

    // use the value of the flag diectly
    _animator.SetBool("DoorIsClosed", !doorIsOpen);
    _animator.SetBool("DoorIsOpen", doorIsOpen);
}
```

It is seems a bit though as if you have a bit of redundancy in your animator. I would either use the Bools in order to trigger a transition or use the Triggers, to have both seems odd.